# How do I get the current HttpContext from a HttpActionExecutedContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I'm writing an exception filter that will log exceptions to Elmah, so I'm doing something like this:

```
class ExceptionLoggingFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter
{
    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actExecContext, 
                                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var httpContext = // what do I do here?
        var errorSignal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(httpContext); // this is Elmah
        errorSignal.Raise(actExecContext.Exception, httpContext);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know what to put in place of the comment question. I've tried to explore the member tree of the `HttpActionExecutedContext` that I get from the method signature to find a way to a `System.Web.HttpContext`, but I can't find any way to get there.

How do I accomplish my goal here?

Comment: `ApiController` does not use `HttpContext` or `HttpContextBase`. You can get to them using `HttpContext.Current`, but only when the webapi is hosted in IIS. If you are hosting in IIS, I believe you can just do `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()`, or follow Joanvo's answer.

Comment: @danludwig: I am running this hosted in IIS, so that will probably work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()
```

uses `HttpContext.Current` under the hood, so although that *might* have worked I did find a better (albeit more roundabout) way to get to it:

```
var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;
object value;
if (request == null
    || !request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out value)
    || !(value is HttpContextBase))
    return null; // Actually I'm returning a Maybe monad here but that's off topic...
}
var httpContextBase = value as HttpContextBase;
return httpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
```

I'm using this together with a maybe monad implementation that lets me use `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext()` as fallback, and so far it's worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Note this will probably only work when the WebAPI is hosted in IIS (not self-hosted):

```
class ExceptionLoggingFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter
{
    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actExecContext, 
                                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //var httpContext = // what do I do here? NOTHING
        var errorSignal = ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext(); // this is Elmah
        errorSignal.Raise(actExecContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am hosting in IIS, so that will probably work. I can verify when I get back to work on Monday =)